# Maximum update depth exceeded. Infinity loop when using TimePickerInput onChange event React.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have TimePickerInput component like this

```
  class TimePickerInput extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.string,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    onChange: function() {}
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this._$input
      .timepicker({ 
        autoclose: true,
        minuteStep: 5,
        showSeconds: false,
        showMeridian: false
      })
      .on("changeTime.timepicker", e => {
        this.props.onChange(e.time.value);
      });
    this._$input.timepicker("setTime", this.props.value);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this._$input.timepicker("setTime", nextProps.value);
  }
  render() {
    const { disabled } = this.props;
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <IconWrapper>
          <Icon className="fa fa-clock-o" />
        </IconWrapper>
        <Input
          innerRef={ref => (this._$input = $(ref))}
          type="text"
          size="16"
          className="form-control"
          readOnly
          disabled={disabled}
        />
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
export default TimePickerInput;
```

When I using it in my another component like this

```
<TimePickerInput  value={notificationConfig.timeToSendAuditReminder} onChange={e => this.onChangeTimeField(e, 'timeToSendAuditReminder')}/>
```

and have onChangeTimeField like this

```
onChangeTimeField = (value, fieldName) => {
    this.props.dispatch(notificationConfigActions.requestUpdateTimeField(value, fieldName))
  }
```

I always get an error like this

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

I cannot find solution how to fix this error. I think it happened when there are a lot of onChange event call between  on("changeTime.timepicker") and when requestUpdateTimeField(value, fieldName) done

Comment: It looks like you are using a jQuery timepicker plugin. If so, which one are you using? Is it possible that the jQuery plugin triggers the `changeTime.timepicker` event when `setTime` is called?  That would cause an infinite loop to occur in your code since you eventually call `setTime` when `changeTime.timepicker` is triggered. You could avoid this by only calling the `onChange` handler in `TimePickerInput` if `e.time.value !== this.props.value`.

Comment: I can't 100% tell, but it looks like by calling `TimePickerInput`'s `onChange` callback the value gets dispatched, so the UI updates which calls the `onChange` callback which again dispatches the value and loops forever. Try putting in a check that the value has changed before dispatching.

Comment: In case of onChangeTimeField, you passing 2 parameters, e --> target element and field name: you will have to fetch the value using e.target.value.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you're using `componentWillReceiveProps`uncondtionally. See this [see this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state). You should use one of [these](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state) instead of `componentWillReceiveProps`as it is considered legacy now.